# Odd Polynomial approximation of $\frac{1}{x}$ as a polynomial around $0$

Tags: functions, polynomials, continuity, approximation, approximation-theory

The taylor approximation of $\frac{1}{x}$ does not exist centered at $x = 0$, as the function is not continuous there. However, there does exist a formula:

$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1 - (1 - x)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1 - x)^n = \frac{1}{x}
$$

However, this function is not of a definite parity (i.e.) $f(-x) \neq -f(x)$ and $f(x) \neq f(-x)$. This is a characteristic of the original function $\frac{1}{x}$.

Is there a polynomial approximation, that maybe looks something like the below sketch?

[image: graph sketch]

This functions is odd and seems plausible to make. I just cannot find it online. Is there any function like what I drew? Again, I am not looking for a taylor approximation, as it won't exist. But perhaps an ad-hoc solution has been made?

Comment: My intuition says no,  given that near 0 $\frac 1 x$ is unbounded whereas any polynomial will be bounded

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ works as an approximation when $|x|<1$  $\hspace{150pt}$
Hence the approximation you stated would in fact work for around $ |1-x|<1$ i.e. $ 0<x<2$

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1 - x)^n$ is the Taylor series of $1/x$ about $x=1,$ with radius of convergence $1.$ Not only does it not have parity, it doesn’t even converge for negative values of $x.$

Comment: @whoisit I think there may have been a miscommunication. The approximation I provided is not an odd polynomial, which is what I am looking for. I edited the title of my question to better fit this.

Comment: @DavidK I am looking for non-taylor series approximations of this. I agree that a taylor series would be impossible for this function.

Comment: The statements that $f(-x)\neq f(x)$ and $f(-x)\neq -f(x)$ suggested that you thought $f(x)$ is defined when $x<0.$ It isn’t. That’s why you got two comments. It’s a side issue, which is why it only merits comments.

Comment: For a function that goes asymptotically to $\pm\infty$ at a point like this, one might use a Laurent sequence. And $1/x$ is it’s own Laurent sequence.

Comment: Well, why you would want to do this seems inexplicable, however taking an odd polynomial like $a_1x+a_2x^3+…+a_nx^{2n-1}$ of sufficiently large degree and finding suitable coefficients by interpolating for your desired positive values should be doable. It may swing quite wildly when away from those chosen points though, while remaining an odd polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) (after some rescaling) to approximate the functions $$g_n(x)=\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{|x|+1/n}$$
in the interval $[-1,1]$ since we have $g_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\ne 0$.

That gives
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n g_n(2\tfrac{k}{n}-1)b_{k,n}(\tfrac{x+1}{2})$$

Here's a graph of some of the approximations:

[image: Approximations]